# Read serial error counters from shell

Tags: serial-port

The TIOCGICOUNT ioctl call can be used to retrieve the interrupt and error counts for a serial port (e.g. how many overruns, parity errors, framing errors).

Is there any way to get this information (error counters) from the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this info is available through procfs:

```
cat /proc/tty/driver/<driver_name>
```

Shows statistics for all ports managed by the specified driver, including parity/framing/overrun error counters.